# Transition-group children must be keyed...but they are keyed

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Trying to use `<animation-group>` in my component template, but getting error:

`[Vue warn]: <transition-group> children must be keyed: <div>`

But I'm pretty sure that they are keyed.

```
//js

Vue.component('instruments', {
template: `
        <transition-group name="fade">
            <div class="instruments">
                <div class="instrument" v-for="(instrument, index) in filteredInstruments" v-bind:key="index">
                    <img v-bind:src="instrument.photo">
                    <span class="name">{{ instrument.name }}</span>
                    <span class="construction">{{ instrument.top }} / {{ instrument.backAndSides }}</span>
                    <span class="price">$ {{ instrument.price }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </transition-group>
    `
}
```

I think that setting `v-bind:key="index"` would take satisfy this, but I get the error pasted above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> You have to give a unique key to your `<div class="instruments">`
>   element since **elements inside a `<transition-group>`, specifically the immediate children, are always**
>   **required to have a unique key** attribute.

If you don't want to give a key to `.instruments`, you can remove that element and assign a `tag` and `class` attributes to `<transition-group>` instead since it renders an actual element which by default is a `<span>`.

```
<transition-group name="fade" tag="div" class="instruments">
```

In this way, the warning would not appear anymore since the immediate children (`.instrument`) have their unique keys assigned to them.

Comment: "..specifically the **immediate** children always are required to have an unique key attribute" ... absolutely the answer! Can't believe that I missed this. I gave the class to the `<transition-group>` component as you suggested above, and removed the extra div. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In some common cases.

You should check to see if there are any elements remain except all elements in for loop.

You may have an incorrect structure like this:

```html
<transition-group name="fade">
  <div v-for="item in listItem" :key="item.id">
  </div>
  <n-button>Load more...</n-button>
</transition-group>
```

**n-button** is the cause. Should move **n-button** out side **transition-group**

Answer (score 0):

just assign a key to every element inside ::

just like that :

```
<transition-group name="fade" tag="div" class="instruments">
   <div class="lorem" key="lorem">lorem ibsum</div>
   <div class="lorem2" key="lorem2">lorem2 ibsum</div>
   <div class="lorem3" key="lorem3">lorem3 ibsum</div>
</transition-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

One or more **keys** is null or undefined.

For example, rendering:

```js
const itemArray = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Alisson"
    },
    {
        id: null,
        name: "Fabinho"
    },
    {
        name: "van Dijk"
    }
]
```

like this:

```html
<transition-group name="fade">
  <div v-for="item in itemArray" :key="item.id">
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</transition-group>
```

will error, since there are **null** and **undefined** id's present.