# <transition-group> children must be keyed: <p>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debugging, vuejs2, vue-component

Related to:

[Transition-group children must be keyed...but they are keyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131926/transition-group-children-must-be-keyed-but-they-are-keyed/54132428)

In:

https://codesandbox.io/s/klvs8

in, component `InventorySectionDraggable`:

```
<template> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <draggable
        class="list-group"
        tag="ul"
        v-model="itemSectionProps.itemSectionCategory"
        v-bind="dragOptions"
        :move="onMove"
        @start="isDragging = true"
        @end="isDragging = false"
      >
        <transition-group type="transition" :name="'flip-list'">
          <p
            class="list-group-item"
            v-for="category in itemSectionProps.itemSectionCategory"
            :key="category.itemSectionCategoryId"
          >
            <i
              :class="
                category.fixed ? 'fa fa-anchor' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin'
              "
              @click="category.fixed = !category.fixed"
              aria-hidden="true"
            ></i>
            {{ category.itemSectionCategoryName }}
            <!-- <span class="badge">{{ element.order }}</span> -->

            <draggable
              v-if="category.itemSectionCategoryItemList"
              class="list-group"
              tag="ul"
              v-bind="dragOptions"
              :move="onMove"
              :list="category.itemSectionCategoryItemList"
            >
              <transition-group class="list-group" :name="'flip-list'">
                <p
                  class="list-group-item"
                  v-for="item in category.itemSectionCategoryItemList"
                  :key="item.itemSectionCategoryItemId"
                >
                  {{ item.itemSectionCategoryItemName }}
                  {{ item.itemSectionCategoryItemStatus }}
                  <!-- <span class="badge">{{ elementDeep.order }}</span> -->
                </p>
              </transition-group>
            </draggable>
          </p>
        </transition-group>
      </draggable>
    </div>

    <div class="list-group col-md-6">
      <pre>{{ listString }}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

all ids in the model are unique (and keyed) but elements somehow disappear during drag and drop. This example worked as expected a few hours ago.

Have no clue what's going on/wrong. Any insight will be much appreciated.

Comment: They are not related; the bugs happen because the data isn't stored in local storage initially but after going through the sections, the props are being passed as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element:

```
<i
  :class="
    category.fixed ? 'fa fa-anchor' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin'
  "
  @click="category.fixed = !category.fixed"
  aria-hidden="true"
></i>
```

was not keyed.